# Ошибка при запуске gulp. Что делать?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
    at createError (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\gulp-uglify\lib\create-error.js:6:14)
    at wrapper (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\lodash\_createHybrid.js:87:15)
    at trycatch (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\gulp-uglify\minifier.js:26:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.minify [as _transform] (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\gulp-uglify\minifier.js:76:19)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:159:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:147:83)
    at doWrite (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:347:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:336:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:274:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\Aplus_smm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:546:20)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас там путь прописан "C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop..."
Галп не дружит с кириллицей и может не корректно работать. Пропишите имя системной папки "Алексей" латиницей

У меня была похожая ситуация. После смены имени системной папки с кириллицы на латиницу все заработало как положено

Answer (score -2):

Думаю сначала нужно ES6 в ES5 конвертировать, а потом минифицировать.

Comment: Каким образом? пишу не на es

Comment: Весь js это es. Этого мало что понять в чем ошибка. Нужен еще как минимум gulpfile.js

Comment: Вот
https://github.com/alexeyklykov/phpacademy/tree/master/gulp
Просто дело в том, что все прекрасно работало, и вдруг такая ошибка появилась, не могу продолжить делать проэкт

Comment: возможно ошибка где то в файлах джс.

Comment: нужен дебаг .pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log)), но сначала установить и подключить var gutil = require('gulp-util');

Comment: хотя можно проще .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e);
         }))

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: Хотя теперь не собирает скрипты(

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?